# Practical upper limit for number of targets

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios4

My app has about 200 classes and I need to make a large number (50+) of variations on the basic app, differing only by about 10 images, and a couple of titles. So I am about to create 2 additional targets (dev/release) for each variation.

Is it possible to use this many targets?  Can Xcode 4.3 handle this (it crashes daily as it is)? Are there specific strategies for managing these targets or is there a better way to manage this many variations?

Comment: *I am about to create 2 additional targets (dev/release) for each variation.* why?

Comment: Customer1 wants a variation with his images, customer2 wants a different variation with her images, ..., customer49 wants...  Dev and release for each.  As I asked, is there a better way?

Comment: xcode's configurations are typically used for the dev/release differences, rather than separate targets.

Comment: No, I am proposing a dev and release for customer1/target1, a dev and release for customer2/target2, ...